# how to pack and export dependent jars in intellij project?

Tags: java, macos, jar, build, gradle

I have a gradle project in intellij 14.

I want to copy the jar files which my project depend on.

How can I gather them for delivery not as one unified jar?

There are so many, and are spread in `~/gradle/caches` ?